# How to get complete production.log from a rails app in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I wanted to have a detailed look into my production.log, but heroku doesn't seem to store them.
Does anyone else, have a solution for that problem.
It would be nice to get it stored safely away.
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Heroku [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) you can see that their logging facility is limited to the last 100 lines whenever you read them back from the console.

If you have a requirement to keep and analyze all of your production logs then it looks like you will have to consider archiving them off-Heroku to, say, S3 or through EC2 logging server.

Comment: hmmm, okay...but how can I accomplish that?

Comment: oh, I just found it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs

thanks bjg for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Just for completeness you can see more than 100 lines with 

heroku logs --tail

It's not what the OP was asking about, this is just in relation to "limited to the last 100 lines"

Answer (score 3):

The Heroku [logging article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) shows you can read up to 1500 lines of your log file. By default, `heroku logs` shows the last 100 lines.

```
heroku logs -n 1500
```

Note that Heroku logging uses Logplex that merges logs from your app as well as from Heroku system. You can filter out logs produced by the system

```
heroku logs -n 1500 --source app
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work in heroku, execute this from your terminal:

`heroku logs -n 200`

or

`heroku logs -t --app <app_name> > any_file_name`

Here the max `-n` limit is 1500