# Heroku production.log file location

Tags: ruby, file, heroku, logging

I wanted to see the contents of my applications log on heroku.com so I've followed [this excellent advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs/5274887#5274887) and have all my log contents.  However I am now curious to find out where my log file actually is as "log/production.log" appears to be empty:

```
C:\>heroku console
Ruby console for ajpbrevx.heroku.com
>> files = Dir.glob("*")
=> ["public", "tmp", "spec", "Rakefile", "doc", "config.ru", "app", "config", "lib", "README", "Gemfile.lock", "vendor", "script", "Gemfile", "log"]
>> files = Dir.glob("log/*")
=> ["log/production.log"]
>> log_file = File.open("log/production.log", "r")
=> #<File:log/production.log>
>> log_file.each_line { |line| puts line }
=> #<File:log/production.log>
>> log_file.lstat.size
=> 0
```

I know I have a full log file as when I do:

```
heroku logs
```

everything is listed, so why does log/production.log not contain anything?  Should I file a ticket with [Heroku](http://status.heroku.com/incident/162)?

Thanks.
Yours in confusion,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heroku addon logging:expanded no longer exists. Some gems mask the logger output too, so for working answers see [this slightly more recent stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098429/heroku-logging-not-working)

To summarise, the nicest solution is to add the following to your config/production.rb file:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger.const_get((ENV["LOG_LEVEL"] || "INFO").upcase)
```

Then, once you've pushed that to heroku, you can see all the logging as it happens with the following command:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Answer (score 7):

Heroku's logs are stored using [logplex](http://www.heroku.com/how/observe). You can read more about how the logging system works [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) but in terms of this question they do not write to your `production.log` file in your app because Heoku wants to keep the app's codebase as small as possible.

So if you want to view all of your logs you need to [drain](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#syslog_drains) it to an external source.

But for watching your app and debugging you can read up to 500 lines or `--tail` your logs such as:

```
 heroku logs -n 500
 heroku addons:upgrade logging:expanded
 heroku logs --tail
```

Comment: Nice.  Thank you Codeglot.  n.b. to others, you will need to 'verify' your Heroku account to get the (free) expanded logging addon, by entering your credit card details.  Heroku don't charge you any money though.

Comment: anyone know an updated answer to this? the addon doesn't exist anymore and I need to see the development / production.log output to debug my deployment!

Comment: @MBHNYC see user208769's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend using Loggly (find it in the Add Ons section on Heroku) - I'm a recent user of Heroku so I don't know if Loggly was added after these posts, but it's definitely a far snazzier, more usable, alternative to piping logs via the console.