# Heroku Rails Application Level Not Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

I have a rails app on Heroku that is not logging at the application level.

Current versions:

- ruby 1.9.3
- rails 3.1.3

In the config/environment/production.rb there are the following lines:

```
    config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    config.log_level = :info
```

What am I missing? What else should I look for?

Comment: are you using the "heroku logs -t" command from a CLI ?

Comment: heroku logs with or without -t returns all log entries. My only app[web.1] entries are the starting for the starting of the Thin web server. No other application logging is present. It's my understanding from the Heroku docs that config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) enables the application logging, but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

How about "heroku logs --source app" ? 
full details here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#types-of-logs

Comment: "heroku logs --source app" returns nothing. I can only conclude that application log entries are not captured and routed by Heroku's Logplex.

Comment: you should try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098429/heroku-logging-not-working