# Rails 4 and Heroku not logging intentional logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

So there a couple of similar questions regarding this but I've tried all of the answers and still can not get my app to do simple logging.

I'm using `Rails 4.2`, `Ruby 2.2`, `Puma` on a `Heroku` free account; So far I've tried:

1. Adding `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`, `config.log_level = :debug`, and `config.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG` to my `production.rb` file as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098429/heroku-logging-not-working), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797763/heroku-rails-application-level-not-logging?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427096/heroku-see-params-and-sql-activity-in-logs)
2. Adding the `rails_12factor` gem as specified by Heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4#logging-and-assets)
3. Added `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG` to my `environment.rb` file as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426540/rails-4-2-cant-see-db-queries-in-heroku-logs-even-though-log-level-set-to-debu?rq=1)
4. Added `$stdout.sync = true` to my `config.ru` file as outlined [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log)

In my app I have the following (none of which I can see in production when using `$ heroku logs --tail` nor in `papertrail`)

```
Rails::logger.debug "Test of 'Rails::logger.debug' logging"
Rails.logger.debug "Test of 'Rails.logger.debug' logging"
puts "Test of 'puts' logging"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was actually that I accidently had two classes with the same name; Apparently `ruby` doesn't doesn't throw an error in that event and because `config.eager_load` is set to `false` in dev, it always worked. The app always ended up loading the class without logging in production first which is why I never saw any messages.

Comment: Which were the two classes with the same name? Were they from your app or from other gems?

Answer (score -2):

If you're on a local environment. This worked for me.

Create a Heroku account. Install Heroku Toolbelt.

From your terminal run heroku login, youll be be prompted qith your username and password, enter your credentials. 
In Gemfile, add the pg gem to your Rails project. Change:

gem sqlite
to

gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'pg', '0.18.1', group: :production
In Gemfile, add the rails_12factor gem::

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
In the terminal, install the gems specified in the Gemfile:

$ bundle install
Ensure config/database.yml is using the postgresql adapter. Change:

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
to

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/production.sqlite3
Commit your changes to git:

$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Heroku config"
In the terminal, create an app on Heroku:

$ heroku create
Push your code to Heroku:

$ git push heroku master
If you are using the database in your application, migrate the database by running:

$ heroku run rake db:migrate

It has worked well for me. I am on windows.