# Basic Rails app deployed using Heroku but errors occuring; can't access logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

I am having a few challenges with a basic app that I have deployed into Heroku.

I attended a Rails workshop yesterday and created the basics of a Twitter-like demo app.

The app works fine on localhost:3000 and is in Github. I deployed to Heroku with no errors in Heroku activities.

However, I get an error when accessing the page: "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served." That's obviously a standard error - the page is http://chirpy-onlysteveh.herokuapp.com/

I'm trying to access the logs but I can't figure out how to to do that either. I've typed heroku logs in the root folder of the app, but I get 'No app specified'. I added '--app chirpy' to the end of that command hoping to fix the issue.

That gives me '! You do not have access to the app chirpy'. That confuses me - how can I get access to the logs? What are the key points I should investigate?

Answer (score 3):

'You do not have access to the ..' surely means something to do with authentication.
You need to do `heroku login` before running `heroku logs..`

Answer (score 1):

As @roxxypoxxy noted `heroku login` from the console should be your first step. If that doesn't work, the key points you should investigate are

1. Generate and add an ssh key to [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)

   - `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate a new key
   - `heroku keys:add` which should look in the default location to add the key.
   - `ssh -v` to test the connection.
   - Also optionally do a `heroku keys` and `heroku keys:remove adam@workstation.local` that you don't recognize.
2. `heroku login` log in to heroku
3. `cd` into your heroku app's directory
4. `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:project.git` to your existing heroku app. You shouldn't need to specify your app name once you're in the app's directory.
5. Retry `heroku logs`

See also

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication
- [Heroku: account does not have access to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126195/heroku-account-does-not-have-access-to-app)

Comment: Thanks for the tips - really useful! I've tried `heroku login` and made sure I'm signed in. I've also done the `ssh` piece. I still have no access using `heroku logs`, and am getting the same message about `! You do not have access to the app chirpy`. I'm in the folder the app was developed in - is there a different folder to be in to access the heroku server logs? Sorry for the lack of detail; I'm a little out of my depth here! Steve.

Comment: I think heroku pulls the app name from the git repo, but can still be explicitly referenced via --app option. Can you log in to the heroku dashboard online? https://dashboard-next.heroku.com/login

Comment: I can log into the Dashboard, yes. No problems evident in there that I can see. Where would the logs be in there? 

I've been able to login to the command line too - when I do it runs updates etc. Trying to call `heroku logs` makes it think for quite a while before it returns `!    You do not have access ... ` etc. Every other command seems to work fine, though - the web page still displays just an error.

Comment: I tried `heroku apps` to check that my app was listed. It was, but under a different name. That gives me access to the logs. Those mean nothing to me. Is there a way to filter the messages to display errors only?

Comment: Did you create the application on a different computer than the one you are using now? And do you remember if you did a second `heroku create` somewhere in all of this? Your local computer should have the same app name as the heroku app name.

Comment: For filtering errors see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607568/can-i-get-heroku-logs-to-return-only-lines-outlining-errors I would also recommend looking into piping, and the unix commands for `head` `tail` and `more` in addition to grep.

Comment: The dashboard should show you a couple of things. Under your username in manage account you can what ssh keys are tied to your heroku account. And under the individual applications there is a tab for access which will tell you who has to individual applications. But it looks like this issue is tied to an app name.