# How to view the logs corresponding to a certain id in Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

hOW to view this id in heroku
    This exception has been logged with id 6ac06o8ho.
    This exception has been logged with id 4bc06o8ho.

Answer (score 0):

To view logs with heroku use

```
heroku logs
```

Play put a line @6ac06o8ho in the logs before the stack trace

Comment: when running "heroku logs", the logs id changed dractically.I want to show both old id and new log id

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean by the id changed but this might be due to new errors, if you want to see old logs see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs

Answer (score 0):

Try this command (select lines which **starts** with exception id):

```
heroku logs | grep -i "\(\@6ac06o8ho\)\|\(\@4bc06o8ho\)"
```

or try less specific (select lines which **contain** id):

```
heroku logs | grep -i "\(6ac06o8ho\)\|\(4bc06o8ho\)"
```

or this(same as above but filter through maximum of 1500 lines):

```
heroku logs -n 1500 | grep -i "\(6ac06o8ho\)\|\(4bc06o8ho\)"
```

Also i was suprised that it's possible to combine `grep` with `--tail` to filter logs in realtime:

```
heroku logs | grep -i "\@[a-z0-9]\{9\}"
```