# Flask-Login and Heroku issues

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-login

I have a sample web application (flask with flask-login running on heroku) at this URL: http://twittaclone.herokuapp.com.

When I run it on my localhost the login functionality works fine. When I push to heroku it freaks out and does not allow users to login (it does allow user registration). Database modifications are being made.

Why would flask login not work on heroku?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_USER' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_USER
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_DB' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_DB

mysql.init_app(app)

if 'SECRET_KEY' in os.environ: app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
else: app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)

def connect_db(): return mysql.connect()


###
# Routing for your application.
###

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = "login"

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    g.db = connect_db()
    return get_user(username)

login_manager.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def home(): return render_template('home.html')

def connect_db(): return mysql.connect()

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
    g.db = connect_db()

@app.teardown_request
def tear_down(exception):
    g.db.close()

@app.route('/main/')
@login_required
def main():
    print("in main")
    tweets, user = get_main()
    follower_count, followee_count = get_follower_info(g.user.username)
    return render_template('main.html', user=user, tweets=tweets, followercount =      follower_count, followeecount = followee_count)


@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    """Logs the user in."""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if current_user is user_logged_in: logout_user()

    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = get_user(request.form['username'])
        if user is None:
            error = 'Invalid username'
        elif not check_password_hash(user.password, request.form['password']):
            error = 'Invalid password'
        else:
            flash('You were logged in')
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('main'))

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'freaks out'?

Comment: It keeps redirecting you to login multiple times.

Comment: try registering with a dummy name like username a, email: a@a, password: a. It will redirect you to login multiple times

Comment: Can I remote debug flask apps with heroku?

Comment: What does running `heroku logs` show? (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs)

Comment: Here are my logs for when the crash happens. It seems to be crashing from login to main. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10021156/logs.txt

Comment: You don't have a route named `main` in your code - how is your redirect working on localhost?

Comment: In heroku it looks like the request is being tore down before the call to main leaving the current user object unauthenticated

Comment: why is the session being destroyed during each call to before_request?

Comment: @SeanVieira I removed flask login, the sessions are still not persisting on each get/post..

Comment: The issue was that I had gunicorn in my Procfile. When I changed it to: web: python app.py. Heroku now serves the content fine. Not sure why gunicorn made the sessions None each request...

Comment: i'm not fluent in heroku, but i do use gunicorn to serve client projects.  it'll swallow exceptions unless you fire it up with the `--debug` flag.  that may give you some insight into why your session is getting trashed.

Comment: by looking at the code, what does get_user() return in heroku? I think if load_user() returns None, login page will be shown normally.

Comment: app.secret_key shouldn't be random.
 [This answer solved my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002236/3811582)

Answer (score 0):

Many years later but this solves your issue: [Heroku gunicorn flask login is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684364/heroku-gunicorn-flask-login-is-not-working-properly/39768181#39768181)

Updated Procfile:

web: gunicorn app:app --preload

Documentation on preloading for gunicorn: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that Heroku uses PostgreSQL. Try referring to their documents https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql