# IPC Connection in Python Discord Bot Dashboard Refusing Connection

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am developing a discord bot called Indigo. It is a bot that has multiple features and uses SQLite. I am working on a Dashboard. I'll give some of my code for the bot, only the relevant stuff because this bot is 600+ lines long.

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import ipc
import aiosqlite
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import psutil
import aiohttp
import random
from io import BytesIO
from itertools import cycle
import datetime
import re
from typing import Optional

data = {}


async def create_users_table():
    async with aiosqlite.connect('users.db') as db:
        await db.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                balance INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
                experience INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
                level INTEGER DEFAULT 1
            )
        ''')
        await db.commit()


us = 0
um = 0
uh = 0
ud = 0

TOKEN = 'no token for you'
VERIFIED_ROLE_ID = 1180692059707953215


class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ipc = ipc.Server(self, secret_key=b"thisisakey")

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Ready!")

    async def on_ipc_ready(self):
        print("IPC server is ready.")

    async def on_ipc_error(self, endpoint, error):
        print(f"Endpoint {endpoint} raised an error: {error}")

    async def update_balance(self, user_id, amount):
        async with aiosqlite.connect('users.db') as db:
            cursor = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM economy WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,))
            data = await cursor.fetchone()
            if not data:
                await db.execute('INSERT INTO economy (user_id, balance) VALUES (?, ?)', (user_id, amount))
            else:
                new_balance = data['balance'] + amount
                await db.execute('UPDATE economy SET balance = ? WHERE user_id = ?', (new_balance, user_id))
            await db.commit()

    async def get_balance(self, user_id):
        print(f"Getting balance for user_id: {user_id}")
        try:
            async with aiosqlite.connect('users.db') as db:
                cursor = await db.cursor()
                await cursor.execute('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,))
                result = await cursor.fetchone()
                print(f"Result of db operation: {result}")
                if result is None:
                    return 0  # return default balance if user_id not found
                else:
                    return result[0]  # return the balance
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


bot = MyBot(intents=discord.Intents.all(), command_prefix='i!')
bot.remove_command('help')

# fast forward to the end (just commands)

bot.run(TOKEN)
bot.ipc.start()
```

The dashboard:

```
import os
from quart import Quart, render_template, redirect, url_for
from quart_discord import DiscordOAuth2Session, requires_authorization, Unauthorized
from discord.ext import ipc
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()


app = Quart(__name__)

app.secret_key = b"thisisakey"
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "true"

app.config["DISCORD_CLIENT_ID"] = os.getenv("DISCORD_CLIENT_ID")
app.config["DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET"] = os.getenv("DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET")
app.config["DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI"] = os.getenv("DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI")
app.config["DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN"] = os.getenv("DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN")

discord = DiscordOAuth2Session(app)
ipcClient = ipc.Client(secret_key=os.getenv("IPC_SECRET_KEY"))


@app.route("/login")
async def login():
    return await discord.create_session()


@app.route("/callback")
async def callback():
    try:
        await discord.callback()
        return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
    except Unauthorized:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    except Exception as e:
        # Log other exceptions for debugging
        print(f"Exception during callback: {e}")
        return redirect(url_for("login"))


@app.route("/")
async def home():
    return await render_template("home.html")


@app.route("/dashboard/")
async def dashboard():
    user = await discord.fetch_user()
    guildCount = await ipcClient.request("get_guild_count")
    guildIds = await ipcClient.request("get_guild_ids")
    try:
        userGuilds = await discord.fetch_guilds()
    except Unauthorized:
        return await redirect(url_for("login"))
    guilds = []
    for guild in userGuilds:
        if guild.permission.manage_guild:
            guilds.classColor = "greenBorder" if guild.id in guildIds else "redBorder"
            guilds.append(guild)

    guilds.sort(key=lambda x: x.classColor == "redBorder")
    return await render_template("dashboard.html", user=user, guilds=guilds)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

My little batch file I use to connect stuff together:

```
@ECHO OFF
START python.exe "C:/Users/no name for you :)/discord bot/backend/followtutorial/bot.py"
ECHO Bot has started running
START python "C:/Users/no name for you :)/discord bot/backend/followtutorial/dashboard.py"
ECHO Dashboard has started running
START http://localhost:5000/
PAUSE
```

Now, this is the dashboards output after trying to log in:

```
 * Serving Quart app 'dashboard'
 * Debug mode: True
 * Please use an ASGI server (e.g. Hypercorn) directly in production
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001 (CTRL + C to quit)
[2023-12-19 09:50:48 -0600] [49028] [INFO] Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001 (CTRL + C to quit)
[2023-12-19 09:50:55 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51735 GET / 1.1 200 352 7178
[2023-12-19 09:50:55 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51735 GET / 1.1 - - 7178
[2023-12-19 09:50:56 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51735 GET /login 1.1 302 939 8295
[2023-12-19 09:50:56 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51735 GET /login 1.1 - - 9301
Exception during callback: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.
[2023-12-19 09:51:05 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51754 GET /callback 1.1 302 199 5259
[2023-12-19 09:51:05 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51754 GET /callback 1.1 - - 5259
[2023-12-19 09:51:05 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51754 GET /login 1.1 302 939 5155
[2023-12-19 09:51:05 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51754 GET /login 1.1 - - 5155
[2023-12-19 09:51:07 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51754 GET /callback 1.1 302 209 293931
[2023-12-19 09:51:07 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51754 GET /callback 1.1 - - 293931
[2023-12-19 09:51:09 -0600] [49028] [ERROR] Error in ASGI Framework
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 992, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1099, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 984, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 727, in sock_connect
    return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 798, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 594, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 1225] The remote computer refused the network connection

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\hypercorn\asyncio\task_group.py", line 27, in _handle
    await app(scope, receive, send, sync_spawn, call_soon)
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\hypercorn\app_wrappers.py", line 33, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\app.py", line 1638, in __call__
    await self.asgi_app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\app.py", line 1664, in asgi_app
    await asgi_handler(receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\asgi.py", line 52, in __call__
    raise_task_exceptions(done)
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\utils.py", line 180, in raise_task_exceptions
    raise task.exception()
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\asgi.py", line 100, in handle_request
    response = await _handle_exception(self.app, error)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\asgi.py", line 357, in _handle_exception
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\asgi.py", line 98, in handle_request
    response = await self.app.handle_request(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\app.py", line 1380, in handle_request
    return await self.handle_exception(error)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\app.py", line 1376, in handle_request
    return await self.full_dispatch_request(request_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\app.py", line 1414, in full_dispatch_request
    result = await self.handle_user_exception(error)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\app.py", line 1007, in handle_user_exception
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\app.py", line 1412, in full_dispatch_request
    result = await self.dispatch_request(request_context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\quart\app.py", line 1506, in dispatch_request
    return await self.ensure_async(handler)(**request_.view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\discord bot\backend\followtutorial\dashboard.py", line 51, in dashboard
    guildCount = await ipcClient.request("get_guild_count")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\ipc\client.py", line 97, in request
    await self.init_sock()
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\ipc\client.py", line 61, in init_sock
    self.multicast = await self.session.ws_connect(self.url, autoping=False)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 825, in _ws_connect
    resp = await self.request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 574, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 911, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1235, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1204, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\No name for you :)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1000, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host localhost:20000 ssl:default [The remote computer refused the network connection]
[2023-12-19 09:51:09 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51754 GET /dashboard/ 1.1 500 - 2257904
[2023-12-19 09:51:09 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51754 GET /dashboard/ 1.1 - - 2257904
[2023-12-19 09:51:09 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51763 GET /favicon.ico 1.1 - - 1017
[2023-12-19 09:51:09 -0600] [49028] [INFO] 127.0.0.1:51763 GET /favicon.ico 1.1 404 207 6134
```

Now, I log in, and then it redirects me to /callback, where I get sent back to /login! Then, I try again and it just spits out this error and gives literally nothing to my browser!

I've tried starting them one at a time, looking for mistakes in my ipc and bot methods, to no avail.

I was expecting it to just send me back my dashboard.

Note: The bot has just normal output through all of this

Comment: I tried looking through the discord.py docs, yet I can't find anything about ipc connections. Could you link that?

Comment: Never mind. I believe I found it. Are you using [this](https://discordpy-ipc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/server/)?

Comment: Wouldn't `self.ipc = ipc.Server(self, secret_key=b"thisisakey")` be `self.ipc = ipc.server.Server(self, secret_key)`?

Comment: Yes, but for the IPC server, it would be `ipc.server.Server` instead of `ipc.Server` just by looking at the docs

Comment: @BlueRobin I'll check

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong about that. From the example in the docs, it shows they used `ipc.Server`. [here](https://discordpy-ipc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/examples/#a-basic-implementation)

Comment: @BlueRobin also I get this error: Exception during callback: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MismatchingStateError: mismatching\_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922045/mismatchingstateerror-mismatching-state-csrf-warning-state-not-equal-in-reque)

Comment: @BlueRobin I just checked through the answers. None of them work for me

Comment: @BlueRobin Fixed it by using discord-ext-ipcx instead of discord-ext-ipc (discord-ext-ipc isnt maintained anymore)

Comment: that was last year...

Comment: @BlueRobin IK, just wanted to update just in case you ever need to use it. I haven't been on here in ages

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using discord-ext-ipcx instead of discord-ext-ipc (discord-ext-ipc isnt maintained anymore)