# Odd exception with mongoid at Heroku

Tags: ruby, mongodb, heroku, mongoid, mongoid3

There is an error at heroku I keep getting. It's a Sinatra app which uses Mongoid. Although I have a Rails app hosted there as well, it doesn't cause any error despite the fact that they have exactly the same mongoid.yml files.

Here are the logs from heroku showing the exception

```
me@ubuntu:~/dev$ heroku logs
2013-01-12T13:51:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure - Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/session/context.rb:43:in `query'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1265:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/session/context.rb:104:in `with_node'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:835:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:38:in `block in <class:App>'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:936:in `dispatch!'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1265:in `block in compile!'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:769:in `block in call!'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:261:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-c839bb60e5f9/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:19:in `first'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:870:in `catch'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:834:in `block in route!'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:921:in `block in invoke'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/query.rb:114:in `first'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:851:in `route_eval'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:755:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-timeout-0.0.3/lib/rack/timeout.rb:16:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-timeout-0.0.3/lib/rack/timeout.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:835:in `[]'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:921:in `catch'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:870:in `process_route'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:769:in `call!'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.3.2/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:48:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:833:in `each'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.3.2/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:27:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-c839bb60e5f9/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:186:in `first'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.3.2/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:17:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:136:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1471:in `synchronize'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.3.2/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:27:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.3.2/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:48:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:99:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.3.2/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:129:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1389:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.3.2/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:48:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1389:in `block in call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exceptional-2.0.33/lib/exceptional/integration/rack.rb:21:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:835:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.3.2/lib/moped/cluster.rb:258:in `with_secondary'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:921:in `invoke'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:872:in `block in process_route'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:833:in `route!'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.3.2/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:48:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-01-12T13:41:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
```

**mongoid.yml**

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: dev123
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        timeout: 20

production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem "mongoid", git: "https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git"
```

Comment: so... what's the exception?

Comment: loot at the logs, that is it.

Comment: Try summarizing the log. Pasting several lines of log entries onto a question in StackOverflow and essentially saying there's my problem, fix it" is a really quick way of getting down voted

Comment: The problem here is that ruby exception logs are stacked so that the actual error is at the top, and basically every line after that is a standard call stack trace. In other words, the logs you pasted in give us all the details except the interesting one.

Comment: @AustinMullins, is there not what you're looking for at the top of the log?

Comment: @alexjamesbrown, stick it out.

Comment: @AustinMullins, <<the logs you pasted in give us all the details except the interesting one>> --- how do I find the interesting one then?

Comment: @Alexandre - search the 'logs' you've posted for the word "error" or "exception" - it's not there.

Comment: @Alexandre - and see this for getting all the logs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs

Comment: @alexjamesbrown, that's what I did. Look at my update, I missed something.

Comment: Can you verify that you actually have the `MONGOHQ_URL` environment variable, and that it's pointing at the right place? Heroku is acting like you tried to log in to `localhost`.

Comment: @AustinMullins,  How do I do that?

Comment: `heroku config` points to `MONGOHQ_URL: mongodb://heroku:d5668b2d5323253eaa50440daf2113cd@linus.mongohq.com:10012/app123456`

Comment: @AustinMullins, it seems like Sinatra doesn't set environment to be production at heroku. Hmmmm...

Answer (score 2):

The error is the app can't connect to a local mongo instance it expects to be running.

If you think that log message is long, you haven't seen Java Spring auto-wiring exceptions =)  Although in this case, the top error message was enough to determine the problem.

I've just got Mongo HQ working with my Rails app on Heroku, so my suggestion is:

Run `heroku config` in your project directory to check that you have defined RACK_ENV=production and MONGOHQ_URL has been defined by Heroku.

If MONGOHQ_URL is not defined as an environment variable on Heroku, chances are you haven't run `heroku addons:add mongohq:sandbox`  to tell Heroku you want a Mongo HQ instance.

If RACK_ENV=production is not defined, just add it with:
`heroku config:add RACK_ENV=production`

After this, restart your app with `heroku restart` and it should work.

FYI for a Rails app (instead of Sinatra) RACK_ENV becomes RAILS_ENV.