# I was able to post data to the MongoDB from heroku but not able to fetch (get) data to the client (MERN Stack)

Tags: heroku, deployment, mern

After successful deployment to Heroku. I was able to register and send data to the database (mongo) and i checked to confirm this on the atlas dashboard. but when I tried to get posts on the client-side. it cant be retrieved. Please what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add details like :

Your router for post

Your Frontend Code where you are fetching data

And if necessary also post errors.

Now as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30659183/13842961)

You can check heroku logs , maybe you will find errors there.
Or else post more details.

You can check your heroku logs by using :

```
heroku logs -t --app app-name
```