# How to permanently save heroku logs?

Tags: heroku, logging

I see how to view heroku logs live

```
heroku logs -t
```

and [how to view the last `n` logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21312682/5783745) e.g.

```
heroku logs -n 500
```

would show the last 500 lines of logs. But the `n` can only be so large because heroku simply doesn't store them (forever). For example, I tried `heroku logs -n 5000` and I get about 1500 lines of logs, but no more.

So suppose I wanted to be able to view logs from farther back, what would I have to do to make them available? Is there some heroku setting/addon I need to implement in order for them to be permanently made available? Or is it the application layer's responsibility to store logs somewhere (e.g. persist them in a database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku logs retain the last 1500 logging records, that are max 1 week old.

There are several [add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging) you can use on Heroku, however they will all have some limitations (max logs, max days) when using a Free Plan.

[Papertrail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging) is a good solution I can recommend: nice dashboard for queries and alerting, saved searches, Free plan including the last 7 days logs. When purchasing a plan (starting from 8$ p/month) the limitations are 'relaxed' and you can keep logs for up to 1 year.

Comment: We tried Papertrail and found it very problematic, since if you exceed the daily volume limit, it drops new log messages, meaning that you end up running blind when under heavy load, when you probably need the tool the most. As such, I really can't recommend it, especially for apps with potentially bursty usage.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but just adding some advice I received in other forums:

- Papertrail is awesome, it's a log management app (nothing to do with the ruby gem of the same name)
- Some suggest not worrying about collecting all logs, but simply using something like Sentry so the errors are reported, which saves sifting through *all* the logs.