# How can you see your rails server running on heroku, so you can see full output while sending REST requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, heroku

Typically if you use your localhost, you can just run

```
rails s
```

from terminal and then when you hit your webserver, you can see the output.

However, when I run

```
heroku run rails s
```

and then I hit my webserver up on heroku, I don't get any output like I do when I "rails s" with localhost.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the live server logs, use this command

```
heroku logs -t
```

There are many more options available, look at this answer [heroku - how to see all the logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `heroku logs` command in terminal to see the log just like you see using `rails s` command.