# We're sorry, but something went wrong. heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I don't see any error message.
but when I run `heroku open` , the browser shows "We're sorry, but something went wrong." 
The app runs fine offline.

the code
https://github.com/codelearner777/blog

could somebody help me?

```
budi@Lenovo:~/blog$ heroku create
Creating rocky-badlands-5818... done, stack is cedar-14
https://rocky-badlands-5818.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/rocky-badlands-5818.git
Git remote heroku added
budi@Lenovo:~/blog$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 139, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (98/98), done.
Writing objects: 100% (139/139), 26.23 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 139 (delta 31), reused 139 (delta 31)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.6.2
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.10
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.19
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.4
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.1
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.4.0
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 2.7.2
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.4
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.4
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.2
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.4
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.4
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.4
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.4
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.4
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.4
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.4
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 52 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (25.95s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-11-06T07:11:59.545861 #1061]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_3696c7b0356812fdd8d08d263aa37657/public/assets/application-51bf096d402cefc1025d96872785d4cf537dbf0073f5dba9572ac26b890c09ae.js
remote:        I, [2015-11-06T07:11:59.560330 #1061]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_3696c7b0356812fdd8d08d263aa37657/public/assets/application-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (3.72s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 30.0MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v5
remote:        https://rocky-badlands-5818.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/rocky-badlands-5818.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
budi@Lenovo:~/blog$ heroku open
Opening rocky-badlands-5818... done

(process:16901): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

Comment: Check your heroku log: `heroku logs -t` which will show you the exact problem. (Why it failed).

Comment: See this post to know more about how to check heroku logs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs

Comment: did you create and migrate you db after uploading you app.

Comment: I cannot post the terminal response after I run heroku run -t because it is too long. But could you tell what should I search for in the terminal?

I did not create or migrate the db. Should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that your application uses database. After creating herokuapp database is not ready yet - you have to "tell it" to use your migration files.

To do this, in terminal run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thank you!! it works! This is the first thing that I made online in my life.lol

Comment: Yeah, I know what you feel :)