# Error with messenger webhook setup

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger

I am using the same verify token but it's giving me error `https://infinite-dusk-17985.herokuapp.com/webhook/` and neither it's responding when I m using it on messenger.

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const request = require('request')
const app = express()

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// index
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world i am a secret bot')
})

// for facebook verification
app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'my_voice_is_my_password_verify_me') {
        res.send(req.query['hub.challenge'])
        res.send('Sucess, Challenge loop crossed')
    }
    res.send('Error, wrong token')
})

// to post data
app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
    let messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging
    for (let i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        let event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i]
        let sender = event.sender.id
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            let text = event.message.text
            if (text === 'Generic') {
                sendGenericMessage(sender)
                continue
            }
            sendTextMessage(sender, "Text received, echo: " + text.substring(0, 200))
        }
        if (event.postback) {
            let text = JSON.stringify(event.postback)
            sendTextMessage(sender, "Postback received: "+text.substring(0, 200), token)
            continue
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200)
})


const token = "EAACKS5K1KvkBAASh07gKvgk9LvjCweLqKxKti1ZBzdzArNFPYNX9ZCx9tu35NNWquJZBuZCdZBLdsZBJAPFhvKgMZBDlazgofkbZAAeE6Hgv3gOh8jRd1W42AAZBIBd7EYNJsADepcpIgSlJEH9kHrup49oT5wZBHZBItnQwwDqr96z4wZDZD"

function sendTextMessage(sender, text) {
    let messageData = { text:text }

    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {access_token:token},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            recipient: {id:sender},
            message: messageData,
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
        } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
        }
    })
}

function sendGenericMessage(sender) {
    let messageData = {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
                "template_type": "generic",
                "elements": [{
                    "title": "First card",
                    "subtitle": "Element #1 of an hscroll",
                    "image_url": "http://messengerdemo.parseapp.com/img/rift.png",
                    "buttons": [{
                        "type": "web_url",
                        "url": "https://www.messenger.com",
                        "title": "web url"
                    }, {
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": "Postback",
                        "payload": "Payload for first element in a generic bubble",
                    }],
                }, {
                    "title": "Second card",
                    "subtitle": "Element #2 of an hscroll",
                    "image_url": "http://messengerdemo.parseapp.com/img/gearvr.png",
                    "buttons": [{
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": "Postback",
                        "payload": "Payload for second element in a generic bubble",
                    }],
                }]
            }
        }
    }
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {access_token:token},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            recipient: {id:sender},
            message: messageData,
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
        } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
        }
    })
}

// spin spin sugar
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('running on port', app.get('port'))
})
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: share error stack trace please.

Comment: Hey I m newbie how can i find that please help me...

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/5xdzhpgkr/ plz find this one

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't share the error stack trace, I am not sure about the reason. But, there is an issue with your code.

For the following code snippet,

```
// for facebook verification
app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
   if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'my_voice_is_my_password_verify_me') {
      res.send(req.query['hub.challenge'])
      res.send('Sucess, Challenge loop crossed')
   }
   res.send('Error, wrong token')
})
```

You would definitely be getting `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

So, update the code with the following.

```
// for facebook verification
app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
   if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'my_voice_is_my_password_verify_me') {
      res.send(req.query['hub.challenge'])
      console.log('Sucess, Challenge loop crossed')
   } else{ 
     res.send('Error, wrong token')
   }
})
```

Comment: have you tested your application locally ?

Comment: I am putting the things on heroku and testing

Comment: why not locally? or is it working fine locally? Anyway try to share heroku logs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a working solution:

```
// my_server.js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');


const app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// spin spin sugar
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('running on port', app.get('port'));
});

/* for facebook verification */
app.get('/webhook', function(req, res) {
  if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'my_voice_is_my_password_verify_me') {
    console.log("Validating webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  } else {
    console.error("Verification failed. Make sure the validation tokens match.");
    res.status(403).end();
  }
});
```

### Few things to take note:

- When you setup the webhook at **developers.facebook.com**, make sure the `Verification Token` you provide their is **exactly the same string as found in the above code** (i.e. 'my_voice_is_my_password_verify_me')
- If you wish to change this token, make sure you **update it at both places**. This is **Very Important**
- If you deploy this code to Heroku, `process.env.PORT` will be your port. **A hardcoded port number might not work!**
- You will notice `app.use(bodyParser.json());` is used here. This is because **Facebook sends JSON data (payload) in the request body**
- Note that you can't write 2 `res.send()` statements it will give you error as mentioned by Mukesh. Once the headers are sent it can't be modified
- Finally as a best practice, you can try to run it locally using `npm run start` or `node my_server.js` and ensure it has no errors like a missing node module & etc **although you won't get a success response while running it locally**