# How do I solve Heroku application error (heroku logs --tail)

Tags: heroku, logging

first of all sorry for my English, as it's not my mother tongue I am not used to it and it might be hard to understand.

I am trying to connect my spike application to heroku in order to get long-term glucose data.

I success all the step without "deploy the branch" step.
(deploy the github branch)

I checked all the API secret (no blanck, qualified with letter length), mongo uri.. I even delete all account (github, heroku) and re-register.. but I could not solve the problem.

I do not know anything about logs and any other server lanugage (do not know even how to call javascript things..)

Can you tell me how to solve this problem?
I will attach the picture in case of you guys do not understand my words..

Thank you!! :)

[image: Application error]

Comment: "I do not know anything about logs" - that's fine, if you can get hold of some logs and edit the relevant looking log lines into the question then we can help you understand them. But you'll have to fetch the logs yourself, and that's what `heroku logs` is for. (And the --tail bit, I'd guess, means leave the log process running and show more logs as they are written.) So start `heroku logs --tail` in one shell or command prompt and then run the deploy step in another window, and you should see logs appear in the first, hopefully with an error that we can then solve.

Comment: Or if you're not actually using console commands it looks like you can select your application in the web management tool and 'view logs' there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37324307/243245

Comment: OHMYGOD!!!!!!!!!!!!! I sovled the problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I saw the logs and it told me what the problem is!!!! Thank you soooooo much!!!!! I was struggling with this problem from yesterday and spend almost..20 hours.. Without your comment it would not be possible to solve!! Thank you sooo sooo sooooooo much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :-)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try logging into your Heroku account and then select your application and finally click on view logs.
[image]
and check the logs that will help you to figure your mistake