# need help deploying ruby on rails to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm very new to coding and I am currently going through a ruby on rails course.

I'm currently trying to deploy to heroku but I keep getting an error

```
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to polar-forest-19639.
```

I've searched through several forums and tried different suggestions with no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't really proceed with this course until I figure this out.

Comment: Do you see any logs? I’m not familiar with Heroku, but precompiling assets should mean its running `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`. What happens if you try to run that exact command locally? Does it generate a few css and js files (and probably some files with a .gz extension)?

Comment: I was able to run that command and no errors came back.  but when I try pushing to heroku I'm getting the error

Comment: Can you follow this and try to see if there are errors in the log? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2671454/10068463

Comment: Can you please post the full error message including the stack track? Same for the log entries written when you try to deploy.

Comment: Please post the full error message log (atleast the last last 100 lines or so). While you doing so, you could try as a quickfix: inside config/application.rb, add
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false But again, to fully understand whats going on, post more of your log.

Comment: here is the full log from when i deploy to Heroku:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0ofLAkhEvio51q5bCPM75C_UNaWELdb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Anybody have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

add in config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.es6 *.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg)
```

if you used the vendor or lib folder add this:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor')
```

Comment: Tried this, no luck still