# How to solve server error (500) while deploying Django project to Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

My Django project works fine locally but as soon as I'm about to deploy to Heroku, I include this piece of code in my `settings.py` file:

```
ENV_TYPE = os.environ.get('ENV_TYPE')

if ENV_TYPE == "HEROKU":
    DEBUG = False
```

Now when I run `python manage.py runserver` locally, I get a `Server Error (500)` in my browser. But as soon as I change `DEBUG` to `True`, everything works fine.

What could be the issue?

Kindly note that I set `DEBUG = True`, but still, there's no way of viewing the error log. It shows a white screen with the `Server Error (500)` on top.

Comment: Check the logs on Heroku

Comment: @RobinZigmond I haven't deployed it yet to Heroku. The scope of the problem is within my local environment.

Comment: Then the error traceback should be on your terminal

Comment: The only error showing on my terminal is `[15/Jun/2020 00:38:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27`

Comment: maybe it write more info in some log file ? When Flask/Django runs on Apache/Nginx then Apache/Nginx saves some information in its log when there is Error 500. BTW: If I correctly rember when you use `DEBUG=False` then Django doesn't serve static files. If your code read some file from url which get from folder `static` then it may not work.

Comment: @furas If it writes some more info in some log file, then that will be good news. However, I currently don't know how to access the log file. Also, I removed every URL from my static folder but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: using Google "heroku logs" I found [heroku - how to see all the logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this problem after playing around my project (in a different branch).

Since I wasn't getting any error message besides the `Server Error (500)` in my browser, I changed the default 500 error page by adding my customised `500.html` in the root of my `templates` folder. It was only then I was able to see the actual error with my project.

The error I saw in my terminal was `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'pages/img/favicon.ico'`. I resolved this by using the command `python manage.py collectstatic --clear`. (See more details in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic))

I ran the server again and everything worked fine.